# Sorting/Comparing with different criterions

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, comparison

So I have data coming in from STDIN and I'm creating objects per line that holds a numeric data field. Based on this field, I want to sort them into either a PriorityQueue or LinkedList. After this sorting, I am going to calculate another value for the objects to hold (the values will be based on frequencies and such). I then want to sort this into another PQ or LL using the second value as the new criterion.

What's the best way to go about sorting the same objects twice using different criterions each time? I don't want to have to create two types of the same object with just distinct compareTo methods. I'm hoping theres a better way.

Comment: Have you thought about using two different [Comparators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insead of implemnting Comparable in the objects themsevles , you should use compartors:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

This enables you to compare the same objects with different compare logic.

Comment: +1  But, as a minor clarification, note that the Comparators _could_ be defined in the objects themselves if it makes sense.  For example, in an Object representing a complete shipping address, you could have many comparators, byName, byAddress, byZipCOde, etc...

Comment: While this is possible, it is debatable if it should be done, as it violates the single responsibility rule